# Tomcat PreResources wildcard webAppMount

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I want to access resources like images in a directory with the endpoint that has a token in middle of the path.

```
http://localhost:8080/mycontext/<token>/images/logo.png
```

I am trying to configure it in `context.xml` and put this config to point the resource to a directory:

```
<Resources allowLinking="true">
        <PreResources
            base="C:/Temp/resources/images"
            className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            webAppMount="/*/images" />
    </Resources>
```

But the `webAppMount` wildcard using `*` is not working. Is it possible? If yes how? If not what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Just wondering if it's the leading slash , e.g. try...      "*/images"     else I don't know.  You should get the resource path after it is considered joined in the code from the call and print it to stdout in the logs folder file catalina.out  and take a look how the path and token were expanded.